# Center a text in assembly language program that display text using library procedures

Tags: assembly, centering, irvine32

I am using library procedures like call WriteString and call WriteDec, how can I center the text?

Comment: By printing enough spaces ahead of the text to put it where you want it.  Those functions don't have any support for automatically finding out the terminal / screen width and printing leading spaces or doing cursor-movement, so that's up to you.  I doubt any Irvine32 functions can query the screen size, so you'll need some Windows console function I guess?

Comment: I am using Irvine32.inc but i don't know how to make this function